# Form link not working

Tags: cognito-forms

The link to my form is not taking me to the form.  Only to a blank page on the Cognito site.  https://www.cognitoforms.com/CarolinaEventConsultants/HHESSeniorClassParentSignUpForm

Comment: So what’s your question?

Answer (score 1):

This form is configured to only be open for submissions from 3/25 to 4/17 and the message indicating that the form is not available was removed.  Please add a message or update the availability dates.

[image]

Please ask "how to" questions on StackExchange that would benefit all users and use our Bug Report option to report problems specific to your form.